# Angular render cryptic JSON data

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I want to render my JSON which has a data embedded inside cryptic object name.

For example, in my JSON my first object value has the key `-Kk0GA4lzQ5Ze8TEaYfS`. I have displayed value using for loop but I also want to get this cryptic object value and insert it inside as a parameter to my `deleteData` function in UI

```html
 <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="well" style="overflow:auto;">
     <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" routerLink="/create">Create</button>
   </div>
   <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>User Id</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let i of array; let a of data; let j = index" [id]="a">
        <td>{{i.firstName}}</td>
        <td>{{i.lastName}}</td>
        <td>{{i.age}}</td>
         <td>{{i.address}}</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="deleteData(j)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
```

```ts
data:any;
dataLen: number;
array: any[] = [];
keyArray: any[] =[];
  constructor(private dataService:DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    return this.dataService.getData()
      .subscribe((data:any) => {
          const myArray = [];
          for(let key in data){
              myArray.push(data[key]);
          }
          this.array = myArray;
    });
  }
```

```json
  {
  "-Kk0GA4lzQ5Ze8TEaYfS" : {
    "address" : "bhandup",
    "age" : 30,
    "firstName" : "aaa",
    "lastName" : "aaa"
  },
  "-Kk0GZ9gp9QqGHRImQ9E" : {
    "address" : "sasdas",
    "age" : 29,
    "firstName" : "test",
    "lastName" : "test"
  },
  "-Kk0GpCy05DkoJaYwlJG" : {
    "address" : "test",
    "age" : 10,
    "firstName" : "test",
    "lastName" : "test"
  },
  "-Kk0JUU91nqeSXmkx_pq" : {
    "address" : "abc",
    "age" : 23,
    "firstName" : "abc",
    "lastName" : "abc"
  },
  "-Kk0Jj6rEgxLJLqtMmtf" : {
    "address" : "jk",
    "age" : 23,
    "firstName" : "abs",
    "lastName" : "abd"
  },
  "-Kk0KzS2LU3AVHxut788" : {
    "address" : "kjkj",
    "age" : 23,
    "firstName" : "aha",
    "lastName" : "hsh"
  },
  "-Kk0M9hewdpfNSeiT8C4" : {
    "address" : "testlast",
    "age" : 10,
    "firstName" : "testlat",
    "lastName" : "testlast"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not mind, an easy way would be to push that cryptic key as a property in the object in your loop:

```ts
.subscribe((data:any) => {
   const myArray = [];
   for(let key in data){
     let a = data[key];
     a.key = key;
     myArray.push(a);
   }
   this.array = myArray;
});
```

Then in your delete function you could pass `i.key` as it would be a property of the object:

```ts
(click)="deleteData(j, i.key)"
```

Hopefully this will work in your use case :)

Comment: thanks its worked for me ... one thing to know (click)="deleteData(i.key)" wont appears in inspect element but click function works ... is that a right behavior? ... where do i capture delete response in component or service

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean, but I think you mean that the request isn't happening to db? Request will not be fired unless there is a subscriber. So when you are doing the request you need to subscribe to the response. Where you do it, is up to you, but probably in the component :)

Comment: I tried getting response in component but it gives me reponse as 200 everytime even if data wont exist in database

Comment: below is my subscription deleteData(data, j){
    this.deleteElement = j;
    return this.dataService.deleterData(data).subscribe((data:any) => { this.status = data.json(); console.log(this.status); })
  }

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined
    at SafeSubscriber._next (display.component.ts:41)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:238)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:185)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:125)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:125)
    at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:83)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.es5.js:1229)

Comment: why are you using return in `return this.dataService....` and How does the `deleteData`-function look like in the service?

Comment: And I'm now going to bed, so I'll look at any possible comments tomorrow :)

Comment: NP ... I am new to angular 2 so was referring one youtube tutorial they have used return type so was trying the same